# I can't seem to get my openpyxl code working

Tags: python, openpyxl

My current challenge is to write some code which does the following:

- Takes user input which will be designated as `batchNumber`
- Takes user input which will be designated as `batchLocation`
- Look through each row in a .xlsx file named `customerData`
- Match the user input `batchNumber` to data in the first column
- Write the `batchLocation` to a cell in the 3rd column adjacent to `batchNumber`

I think this is a lot easier than I'm making it out to be but I seem to be going round in circles.

The excel document is structured as...

```
Batch Number Product Type Location

1234 Guitar *Blank*

2345 Drums *Blank*
```

I've tried altering the ATBS code from the excel section but can't seem to get it to work with user input instead of data from a dictionary. The code runs without errors but the changes aren't made unless the data appears in the very first row? I've also tried using `iter_rows()` but haven't had much success.

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('customerData.xlsx')
sheet = wb['SalesOrders']

# User Input of data 
CUSTOMER_UPDATE = {}
batchNumber = str(input('Please scan the batch number: '))
batchLocation = input('Please scan the location: ')
CUSTOMER_UPDATE[batchNumber] = batchLocation

# Loop through the rows and update the location
for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row): #Used to skip the first row as it is only a header.
    productName = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value

if productName in CUSTOMER_UPDATE:
    sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = CUSTOMER_UPDATE[productName]

wb.save('customerDataCopy.xlsx')
```

Comment: Haven't looked much into your code yet, but it looks like the `if` statement should be inside the `for` loop? Otherwise it is only going to act on your last row.

Comment: Dammit! You're right, it's now working. I feel like an idiot.

Comment: No worries, these things happen to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to test the `productName` for every row, so you want to indent the `if` under the `for` loop, like this:

```py
# Loop through the rows and update the location
for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row): #Used to skip the first row as it is only a header.
    productName = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value
    if productName in CUSTOMER_UPDATE:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value = CUSTOMER_UPDATE[productName]
```